# Unique Pending Intent for Alarm Manager

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I am using Alarm Manager to receive system triggers at particular set time. I am using PendingIntents and BroadcastReceiver for this. I need to create 4 unique pending intents for alarm manager to trigger at 2 different times(start1,end1, start2,end2). The issue I am facing is in the OnReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver I get 2 calls for each intents instead of 1 call. So in the end I have total of 8 calls(start1,start1,end1,end2,start2,start2,end2,end2) whereas I should be getting 4 calls (start1,end1,start2,end2).

I have tried using unique Request Code, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT & PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT but none of them seem to solve this problem. I found out that system triggers alarm twice for same request code.

```
//creating the intent & intent filter
//Action is custom action

IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(action);
Intent intent = new Intent(action);

//generating unique request ID
int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
intent.putExtra("requestID",requestID);

//creating pending intent
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext,requestID,intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT|PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT); 

//adding pending intent to alarm manager
mAlarmMgr = (AlarmManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
mAlarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, alarmIntent);
```

Any suggestions would be of great help!

Thanks

P

Comment: Code which you have provided is messed up.Please provide full code from starting an `Intent` to making an alarm request.Is it your full code?

Comment: Have you tried using `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` only without `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`?

Comment: Try with FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT !!